# Syntax error when i tried to update user table and setting password

Tags: mysql, xampp

mysql> update mysql.user set password=password<'legend'> where user='root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where
 user='root'' at line 1

Comment: perhaps you meant "(" instead of "<" !?!

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('legend') WHERE User='root';
```